# Rails Joins inherited relation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a relation with

MODEL USER

```
has_one :user_information
has_many :user_tags
```

MODEL USER_INFORMATION

```
BELONGS_TO :user
```

AND HAVE A MODEL

USER_TAG

```
belongs_to :user
```

question:

How to acess a ORDER BY USER_INFORMATION IS NOT NULL FROM USER_HAST_TAG with joins

NEED:

```
@USER_TAGS=UserTag.joins(:user).where(:active => true).order("user.user_information is not null desc")
```

Im Try with

```
@USER_TAGS=UserTag.joins(:user,{:user => :user_information}).where(:active => true).order("user.user_information is not null desc")
```

ouput mysql Unknown column user.user_information

Answer (score -1):

I think you try this way. It might helps you,

```
UserTag.includes({user: [:user_information]}).where(:active =>true).order("user_informations.id is not null desc")
```